# Need help for proper rectilinear projection of equirectangular panoramic image

Tags: 3d, trigonometry, panoramas, projective-geometry

With the algorithm below, when the projection plane is tangent to the equator (the center line of the equirectangular image), projected image looks rectilinear.

[image: Rectilinear image]

But when the projection plane is tilted, (py0 != panorama.height/2), lines are warped.

[image: Warped image]

The two last "lines" in the algorithm below needs to be "rectified", in order to adjust px and/or py when the center line of the destination plane is not at the same level than the center line of the equirectangular image.

```
  // u,v,w :
  //     Normalized 3D coordinates of the destination pixel

  // elevation, azimuth:
  //     Angles between the origin (sphere center) and the destination pixel

  // px0, py0 :
  //     2D coordinates in the equirectangular image for the
  //     the destination plane center (long*scale,lat*scale)

  // px, py:
  //     2D coordinates of the source pixel in the equirectangular image
  //     (long*scale,lat*scale)

  angularStep=2*PI/panorama.width;
  elevation=asin(v/sqrt(u*u+v*v+w*w));
  azimuth=-PI/2+atan2(w,u);
  px=px0+azimuth/angularStep;
  py=py0+elevation/angularStep;
```

I can compute the intersection p between the normal of each destination pixel and the sphere, then convert cartesian coordinates to long/lat using available C code:

[image: projection]

But I know there's a simpler and much less time consuming method, involving adjusting source pixel coordinates in equirectangular image (px,py) knowing the longitude/latitude (px0,py0) at which the center of the projection plane intersect the "sphere".

Could you help please ?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this to work using the formula for gnomonic projection in a webgl shader http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GnomonicProjection.html

```
            float angleOfView   

            float phi1          
            float lambda0     //centre of output projection

            float x = PI2*(vTextureCoord.s - 0.5) ;  //input texture coordinates, 
            float y = PI2*(vTextureCoord.t - 0.5 ); 

            float p = sqrt(x*x + y*y);

            float c = atan(p, angleOfView); 

            float phi = asin( cos(c)*sin(phi1) + y*sin(c)*cos(phi1)/p );

            float lambda = lambda0 + atan( x*sin(c), (p*cos(phi1)*cos(c) - y*sin(phi1)*sin(c)));

            vec2 tc = vec2((lambda /(PI*2.0) + 0.5, (phi/PI) + 0.5); //reprojected texture coordinates 

            vec4 texSample  =  texture2D(tEqui, tc); //sample using new coordinates
```

Comment: Hi. I was looking for a solution to this and I found your answer that seems to work well. I have a question though. Why do you apply those formulas to the texture coords in the beginning and to the lambda and phi in the end? Also is PI2, PI * 2?